# define_method not using variables until method is called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having trouble getting a variable from a for loop. It seems i(var) is calculated later on and not class definition which I totally require.

```
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > class Pat
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 ?>  for i in 39..47
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 ?>    define_method("a#{i}".to_sym) do
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 >         puts i 
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 ?>      end
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 ?>    end
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 ?>  end
#=> 39..47 

ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > p = Pat.new
#=> #<Pat:0x103c31140> 

ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > p.a39
47
#=> nil 

ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > p.a49
NoMethodError: undefined method `a49' for #<Pat:0x103c31140>
    from (irb):69
    from :0
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > p.a40
47
#=> nil
```

Should I be using def? if so how can I achieve the dynamic method names that I achieved here with def.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's happening there is a bit subtle... the traditional for loop that you're using shares the single "i" variable across all iterations... The closure (block password to define_method) is capturing "i" - and since there is only one "i", they will all (at the end of the for loop) capture the final value of "i", which is the last value in the range that you're looping over.

Alternative solution:

```
class C
  (1..10).each {|i| define_method("a#{i}") { puts i } }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>> class Pat
..   (37..47). each do |i|
..       define_method("a#{i}".to_sym) do
..         puts i
..       end
..     end
..   end #=> 37..47
>> Pat.new.a40 #=> nil
40
>> Pat.new.a50
NoMethodError: undefined method `a50' for #<Pat:0x00000100b39bc8>
```

Edit: sorry I don't have time for a proper explanation, but a quick search brought up a blog post where you'll be able to get the gist of it: http://paulphilippov.com/articles/enumerableeach_vs_for_loops_in_ruby

Answer (score 2):

Although @RyanLeCompte's answer is better and cleaner (and sufficiently describes the cause of the problem), here's an alternative solution, fashioned after the way this problem is typically avoided in JavaScript:

```
class Foo
  for i in 1..9 do
    define_method "a#{i}", &(lambda{|x| lambda{puts x}})[i]
  end
end
Foo.new.a1
#=> 1
Foo.new.a9
#=> 9
```

*Don't accept this answer, but do vote it up if it helps you level up your metaprogramming. :)*